# What is a model in Julia Flux 0.13 and higher?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

(also posted in Julia discourse https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-is-a-model-in-julia-flux-0-13-and-higher/100653)

I want to use Julia Flux for machine learning with custom models (not neural networks, so I won't be using/combining models provided by Flux). I want to do it with Flux because I want access to various advanced gradient decent algorithms.

To do so I intend to use the training API (https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/reference/#Training-API-Reference)

The problem is that the documentation is not very detailed. For example there are functions like

```
Flux.setup(rule, model)
```

and

```
Flux.train!(loss, model, data, opt_state)
```

however nowhere in the API there is a description of what the `model` is and what form should it take.

As a test problem, consider matrix factorization. That is, given matrix `A`

```
using Random

dim = 2

A = rand(dim, dim)
```

find such `x` and `y` that

```
x * y' ≈ A
```

I would guess that the `model` should be defined as `model(x, y) = x * y'`, but then `Flux.setup(AdaGrad(), model)` produces a warning

```
Warning: setup found no trainable parameters in this model
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you link to has an example of what a `model` is in the documentation of `Flux.Train.setup`:

```
julia> model = Dense(2=>1, leakyrelu; init=ones);

julia> opt_state = Flux.setup(Momentum(0.1), model)  # this encodes the optimiser and its state
(weight = Leaf(Momentum{Float64}(0.1, 0.9), [0.0 0.0]), bias = Leaf(Momentum{Float64}(0.1, 0.9), [0.0]), σ = ())

julia> x1, y1 = [0.2, -0.3], [0.4];  # use the same data for two steps:

julia> Flux.train!(model, [(x1, y1), (x1, y1)], opt_state) do m, x, y
         sum(abs.(m(x) .- y)) * 100
       end
```

It might be easier to look at the "Fitting a straight line" part of the docs:

https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/overview/

Comment: But how do you use a custom model (not constructed with Flux built-in layers) with `Flux.setup`? Do the weights need to be in a struct with `@functor` applied or is it possible to use `setup` with functions defined like `layer1` and `layer2` here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/#Building-Layers

Comment: That might be a useful separate question!